# how to set up path in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

i installed ruby and then gem of rails. when i am trying to start server using

```
ruby script/server
```

i am getting an error

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/server (LoadError)
```

Comment: this question is not programming related

Comment: wrong tag, should be "windows"

Answer (score 1):

You have to first navigate to the demo directory by "cd command" and then input

```
ruby script/server
```

EDIT:
in windows it should be

```
ruby script\server
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder that the ruby.exe file is in to your PATH environment variable list:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Comment: if you look at the error, its thrown by ruby.exe. so its not a prob of env-path

Answer (score 0):

In the start menu type "Advanced system settings" (requires admin). Click on the Advanced tab and click on the Environment Variables button. Under System variables find the variable named path and double click it. In the Variable value go to the end and place a semicolon on the end if one is not there all ready. And enter the path to your ruby installation.