# Python code in C++

Tags: c++, python, eclipse, python-embedding

I want to use some Python code in my C++ framework to plot some statistics. I have already found the following posting (about how to embedd python in c++) but following the instructions did not lead to success: [Embed python code in C++ (Windows + minGW + Python 2.7.2 + Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198537/embede-python-code-in-c-windows-mingw-python-2-7-2-eclipse)

```
#include "Python.h"
int main(int f_argc, const char* f_argv [])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    const char* pythonScript = "print 'Hello, world!'\n";
    int result = PyRun_SimpleString(pythonScript);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I am sorry, but I do not have much experience with make files or attaching static or dynamic libraries....

I have to following system:
Windows 7 + 64 Bit + Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: Juno Service Release 1 + mingw + python32

under path and symbols:
+ added include directory of python32
+ added library "python32" which should correspond to libpython32.a
+ added library path

The compiling and linking seems to work, but when I try to start the exe, I get the following message:

"The program can't start because python32.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

I cannot understand this message because I try to add a static library (libpython32.a) to the source. Could you give me a gentle push in the right direction?

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT:
added makefile and objects.mk

MAKEFILE
    ################################################################################
    # Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
    ################################################################################

```
-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: Sandbox.exe

# Tool invocations
Sandbox.exe: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
@echo 'Building target: $@'
@echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
g++ -L"C:\Python32\libs" -o "Sandbox.exe" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
@echo 'Finished building target: $@'
@echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
-$(RM)     $(C++_DEPS)$(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) Sandbox.exe
-@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

OBJECTS.MK

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

USER_OBJS :=

LIBS := -lgdi32 -ljpeg-8 -ltiff-5 -lpython32
```

Comment: BTW Also consider the opposite: make your C++ statistics code into a Python module. SWIG will make it easier for you.

Comment: See [Embedding Python on Windows: why does it have to be a DLL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3953039/222914)

Answer (score 3):

On Windows the program search path and the shared library search path are controled by the same environment variable, `PATH`. To embed Python, you need to put the directory that contains `python32.dll`, typically `c:\python3.2`, on your `PATH`.

Explanations how to change `PATH` on Windows are easily googled; see for example [this videocast](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96) that explains it for running Python, or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3087199/1600898) that explains the procedure for Ruby.

Running Python on Windows is also covered in [the Python on Windows FAQ.](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The static library (libpython32.a) you throught is not a real static library, it contains only the definiation of python32.dll. so it is nothing but a wrapper to python32.dll.

you must add the python install folder in your Windows PATH, so that Windows could found the dll by itself.